# Avoid invalid directory path

Tags: android

I have a constant which determines the storage path of the device.

```
File STORG_PTH = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/");
```

User can determine it`s own download directory by entering it in a editText.

It gets checked with below code if it`s a valid path but how can i avoid if a user for example enters more slashes(/) like '/storage/emulated/0//just/to///see'?

Thank you in advance.

```
File TEST = Constants.STORG_PTH;
    String STORAGEPTH = TEST.toString();
    String Test = "/storage/emulated/0/justatest/to/see";

    if (Test.startsWith(STORAGEPTH)) {
        Log.d("STORAGE PATH: ", STORAGEPTH + " IS VALID!");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("STORAGE PATH: ", STORAGEPTH + " IS INVALID!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InputFilter` to block specific characters like this:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

String blockCharacter = "/";

      @Override
      public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
         if (source != null && blockCharacter.contains(("" + source))) {
               return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

and then:

```
EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
e.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: Thx this is what I'm looking for, can the filter contain mutiple characters like ()*&#$@:;,.'£

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple characters.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use the standard Java File IO methods? Like this:

```
File f = new File(someCustomPath);
if (f.isDirectory()) {
    // Do something ...
}
```

If you do this, you might also want to check if the directory from your path is readable with `isReadable()`.

Comment: I already use this together with exists () but I want also to avoid that the user enters invalid characters.

Comment: To prevent invalid characters, you could simply restrict the input of your `EditText` by adding something like `android:digits="abcde.....012345789"` in your XML